# Internal consistency of C structures

Tags: c, struct, memcmp

If I have two C structures initialised to have identical members, can I guarantee that:

```
memcmp(&struct1, &struct2, sizeof(my_struct))
```

will always return zero?

Comment: I've created an example that shows the padding issue the other answers mention : http://ideone.com/NdLJG4 .

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's an excellent example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can safely `memcmp` a structure to test for equality.

From C11 *§6.2.6.6 Representations of types*

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type,
>   including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation
>   that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values.

This implies that you'd need to write a function which compares individual elements of the structure

```
int my_struct_equals(my_struct* s1, my_struct* s2)
{
    if (s1->intval == s2->intval &&
        strcmp(s1->strval, s2->strval) == 0 && 
        s1->binlen == s2->binlen &&
        memcmp(s1->binval, s2->binval, s1->binlen) == 0 &&
        ...
        ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

No, two structures with all members equal may sometimes not compare equal for `memcmp()`, because of [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86).

One plausible example is as follows. For the initialization of `st2`, a standard-compliant 32-bit compiler could generate a sequence of assembly instructions that leave part of the final padding uninitialized. This piece of padding will contain whatever happened to be there on the stack, whereas `st1`'s padding will typically contain zero:

```
struct S { short s1; long long i; short s2; } st1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int main() {
  struct S st2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
  ... at this point memcmp(&st1, &st2, sizeof(struct S)) could plausibly be nonzero
}
```

Comment: You can make a structure packed so that it won't pad any (uninitialised) bits in it.

Answer (score 2):

<s>If both variables are global or static, and their members were initialized at init time of the program, then yes, they will compare equal with `memcmp()`.</s> (Note, most systems just load the data pages into zero initialized pages, but the C standard does not guarantee this behavior.)

Also, if one of the structures were initialized with the other using `memcpy()`, then they will compare equal with `memcmp()`.

If both were initialized to some common value with `memset()` first before their members are initialized to the same values, then they will also compare equal with `memcmp()` (unless their members are also structures, then the same restrictions apply recursively).

Comment: I didn't downvote but I don't think C11 s6.7.9.10 backs this up the first paragraph.  It reads as if initialisation of statics/globals is a series of assignments of members to 0 or NULL.  If this is correct, s6.2.6.6 suggests that any padding bytes would have undefined value

Answer (score 2):

Beside the obvious case of struct padding, it is not even guaranteed for single variables. See the footnote for 6.2.6.1 (8):

> It is possible for objects `x` and `y` with the same effective type
>   `T` to have the same value when they are accessed as objects of type
>   `T`, but to have different values in other contexts. In particular, if
>   `==` is defined for type `T`, then `x == y` does not imply that
>   `memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof (T)) == 0`. Furthermore, `x == y` does not
>   necessarily imply that `x` and `y` have the same value; other
>   operations on values of type `T` may distinguish between them.

Comment: This is a great point. A concrete example of this is floating point types where there are +'ve and -'ve 0 values that compare equal but have different bit patterns.

Comment: Its probably worth noting that floats also provide the opposite case: i.e. take two doubles `x=y=1.0/0` they compare as unequal, `x!=y`, but have `memcmp(&x,&y,sizeof(double))==0`.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You can guarantee that they're identical if you ensure that both entire memory blocks are initialised before they're populated, e.g. with `memset`:</strike>

```
memset(&struct1, 0, sizeof(my_struct))
```

**EDIT** leaving this here because the comment stream is useful.

Comment: that's not backed by language semantics - padding bytes always take unspecified values, which in particular means that compilers are free to overwrite ambient padding when assigning to members; no idea if that happens in practice, though...

Comment: @Christoph: Are you sure about that? If so, I don't even want to think about how many protocol stacks will just suddenly break on such a system.

Comment: @user315052: *When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values* (C11 6.2.6.1 §6)

Comment: @Christoph: I read the footnote, though, and the intent of that phrase was to allow structure assignment to be implemented with `memcpy()`.

Comment: @user315052: the footnote reads *Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.*, which is more or less the opposite of your claim, ie structure assignment can be implemented without `memcpy()`ing the whole blob

Comment: @Christoph: I was reading footnote 42 in C99. I don't have C11 in front of me at the moment.

Comment: it's easy to come up with other reasons for this restriction, eg on architectures where the size of a logically addressable unit of memory (byte) is smaller than the unit of physically addressable memory (word), ie where byte-wise access has to be emulated via shifts and such; having to keep padding intact would mean that we had to read the padding every time we want to write to a less-than-word-sized member

Comment: @Christoph: C already allows for a `char` to be more than 8 bits, so I don't believe such a system would be implemented that way.

Comment: @user315052: maybe I want to run a POSIX system on a DCPU-16 ;); even if my example is contrieved, I do believe my point stands going by guarantees made by the standard alone

Comment: @Christoph: Reading that phrase again, it is not clear to me if "including in a member object" means the object is a member object, or if the value is being stored to a member of the object. That is, it is not clear from the sentence if the value itself is of structure or union type. It would make sense if a structure is a member of another structure, then structure assignment to the member may affect padding to the containing structure. I am not sure if I can buy assignment to other members, since they should be governed by the rules already set out earlier in the same section.

Comment: @user315052 I was going to point out the same ambiguity.  It's unclear whether the phrase "value stored" relates to the value stored in the _entire structure_ (i.e. as a single assignment), or to storing values within individual members of that structure.

Comment: @Alnitak: it's not as clear as it could be, but the gist is that storing into a structure invalidates padding, regardless of whether you access the structure as a whole via assignment (`a = b`) or only target a specific member (`a.foo = 42`), which is what the part *including in a member object* refers to

Comment: note that after having re-read the relevant parts of the standard, my claim that the value of padding bytes is *always* unspecified appears to be incorrect - it only gets invalidated by storage into the structure (assignment to the structure or its members) - if you do all your modifying manipulations byte-wise (cast to `char*`, `memcpy()`, ...), padding bytes should retain their values